# Python y SQLite, problemas con mi base de datos

Tags: python, sqlite

Resulta que estoy creando una base de datos para inscribir a estudiantes en diversos cursos, el problema me surgió cuando llegué a la parte en donde quiero consultar con mi base de datos un estudiante, es decir, si el estudiante está previamente registrado, que me deje hacer la consulta, pero si es nuevo que me deje agregarlo y guardarlo a la base de datos.

Esto es lo que fui armando:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

ventana = Tk()

ventana.title ('------- Administradores -------')
ventana.geometry ('350x150+500+250')
Label(ventana, text = "Usuario:").pack()
caja1 = Entry(ventana)
caja1.pack()

Label(ventana, text = "Contraseña:").pack()
caja2 = Entry(ventana, show = "*")
caja2.pack()

def login():
 # Connect to database
 db = sqlite3.connect('C:\sqlite\gui\GDK')
 c = db.cursor()

 usuario = caja1.get()
 contr = caja2.get()

 c.execute('SELECT * FROM Administradores WHERE Usuario = ? AND Contraseña = ?', (usuario, contr))

 if c.fetchall():
     ventana.withdraw()
     ventana2 = Tk()
     ventana2.title ('------- Cursante -------')
     ventana2.geometry ('350x150+500+250')

     Boton2 = ttk.Button (ventana2, text = "Existente", command = open('C:\sqlite\gui\GDK'))
     Boton2.pack()

     Boton3 = ttk.Button (ventana2, text = "Nuevo", command = open('C:\sqlite\gui\GDK'))
     Boton3.pack()

     if Boton2 is True:
         ventana2.withdraw()
         ventana3 = Tk()
         ventana3.title ('------- Existente -------')
         ventana3.geometry ('350x150+500+250')

         Label(ventana3, text = "DNI:").pack()
         caja3 = Entry(ventana3)
         caja3.pack()
         def dni():
            # Connect to database
            db = sqlite3.connect('C:\sqlite\gui\GDK')
            c = db.cursor
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM Cursante WHERE DNI = ?', (DNI))
            DNI = caja3.get()
            Boton2 = ttk.Button (text = "Existente", command = dni).pack()
            ventana3.mainloop()

     if Boton3 is True:
                ventana4 = Tk()
                ventana4.title ('------- Nuevo -------')
                ventana4.geometry ('350x150+500+250')
                Label(ventana4, text = "DNI:").pack()
                caja4 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja4.pack()

                Label(ventana4, text = "Apellido:").pack()
                caja5 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja5.pack()

                Label(ventana4, text = "Nombre:").pack()
                caja6 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja6.pack()

                Label(ventana4, text = "Email:").pack()
                caja7 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja7.pack()

                Label(ventana4, text = "Telefono:").pack()
                caja8 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja8.pack()

                Label(ventana4, text = "Institucion_representada:").pack()
                caja9 = Entry(ventana4)
                caja9.pack()

                def Nuevo():
                # Connect to database
                    db = sqlite3.connect('C:\sqlite\gui\GDK')
                    c = db.cursor()

                    DNI = caja4.get()
                    Apellido = caja5.get()
                    Nombre = caja6.get()
                    Email = caja7.get()
                    Telefono = caja8.get()
                    Institución_representada = caja9.get()
 else:
     messagebox.showerror (title = ('Login incorrecto'), message = ('Usuario o contraseña incorrecta'))

 c.close()
Boton1 = ttk.Button (text = "Login", command = login).pack()


ventana.mainloop()
```

El tema es que no sé qué comando usar para que me realice una consulta `:/, "open"` no me deja, si alguien pueda darme una respuesta o quiere ponerse en contacto conmigo por favor me sería de gran ayuda!

Comment: que quieres decir con `:/, "open"`